# Given an assembly with xUnit unit tests what is the command to list all the tests without running?

Tags: xunit

I am looking for the xUnit equivalent of the NUnit's `--explore` command line switch. I am looking at **xunit.console.exe** help output and just do not see it.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way with the xunit.console, however, if your test project is using `xunit.runner.visualstudio` you should be able to get this using the dotnet cli. Try running the following command

`dotnet test -t`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21

Comment: Yeah, I managed with dotnet command line. But my question is about the xunit console runner.